# Flume Streaming Data from Facebook

Tags: flume

Please let me know whether it is possible to get data from Facebook to HDFS using Flume or Not,
If yes can you please post the Configuration(Source) for flume.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flume to read facebook page/feed/post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857077/flume-to-read-facebook-page-feed-post)

Answer (score 0):

Some information about how to streaming data from Social Media (Facebook) are on

https://github.com/DataDanSandler