# Flume to read facebook page/feed/post

Tags: facebook, hadoop, flume, bigdata

Anyone knows how to use flume so that it's reads data from a Facebook page?

Actually I want to have a flume agent that reads a specific Facebook page and extracts all the information such as post/feed and push the data into Hadoop databases.

Comment: Have you come across anything in your search that is a Facebook Flume source? If not, you'll likely have to hookup some streaming into Flume like a Kafka producer, for example.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Flume Streaming Data from Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675248/flume-streaming-data-from-facebook). The [sentiment_analysis project](https://github.com/DataDanSandler/sentiment_analysis)  has an overview containing the following:

> 1) Sample PHP code for the Facebook HTTP gets and posts
>
> 2) Flume configuration for a Facebook HTTP Source
>
> 3) The flume agent
>
> 4) A INI file for the Facebook PHP code
>
> 5) DDL for a Facebook hive table

Comment: I went to through the given code but it doesn't read it from facebook page. The facebook source is not pointing to any particular page or keywords unlike twitter. Please suggest